# pandas - unstack with most frequent values in MultiIndex DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I've got this sample DataFrame `df`:

```
GridCode,User,DLang
3,224591119,es
3,224591119,ja
3,224591119,zh
4,224591119,es
6,146381773,en
9,17925282,ca
```

I would like to group the `User` field, keeping only the most frequent `DLang` code, then unstack and count the numbers of `User` in each `GridCode`. So far I did:

```
d = df.groupby(['GridCode','DLang']).size().unstack().fillna(0)
```

which correctly returns:

```
DLang     ca  en  es  ja  zh
GridCode                    
3          0   0   1   1   1
4          0   0   1   0   0
6          0   1   0   0   0
9          1   0   0   0   0
```

However, as you can see in `df`, some users have multiple `DLang` entries (e.g. User 224591119), but I only want to count their most frequent `DLang` code (e.g for that user, it is `es`). The resulting dataframe would be:

```
DLang     ca  en  es
GridCode                    
3          0   0   1
4          0   0   1
6          0   1   0
9          1   0   0
```

Comment: How do you want the GrideCode to be handled with regard to counting User 224591119, since he used `es` in both GrideCode 3 and 4? Effectively counting him just twice, instead of four times?

Comment: Also, I think the example data you provided is cut off by a few rows (there is only one `ca` entry, not 3). I changed this, but you may want to update/check the example data and the resultant data frames.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, count how many times a specific `DLang` occurred, averaging across `GridCode`.

```
g = df.groupby(['User','DLang']).count().reset_index()
g = g.rename(columns={'GridCode':'occurrences'})
```

Then, use the `first()` function to find the most frequent/max occurrence for each user.

```
h = g.groupby('User').first().reset_index()
```

Merge just the most frequent/max occurrence df with the original input. This will drop rows where users used a `DLang` other than the most frequent

```
j = pd.merge(df,h, on=['User','DLang'])
```

Finally, average across users to get your final counts.

```
final_df = j.groupby(['GridCode','DLang']).size().unstack().fillna(0)

DLang     ca  en  es
GridCode            
3          0   0   1
4          0   0   1
6          0   1   0
9          1   0   0
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Regarding your previous comment, that dataframe is correct. I just wanted to assign the most frequent language to each user, no matter the GridCode. Then, for each GridCode, counting how many users are in each grid. So in previous example, it is correct that there are one 'es' User in Grid 3 and one 'es' User in Grid 4.